# Client side CustomMessageInspector, how to make this code work from within the exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interceptor

**Hi,**

I am running CustomMessageInspector on service side and now I need to to the same on client side. Is is however not implemented the same way in a client. I have found this code :

https://gist.github.com/1076635

But I have a hard time to get this running from within the winform project, do I really have to put this in a class library to get it to work?

**BestRegards**

Edit 1:

This is how my instanciation of the service looks like on the client side.

```
    ClientService clientService = new ClientService();
    InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(clientService);

    DuplexChannelFactory<MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService> factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService>(context, connectionName);
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = anvandarNamn;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
    return factory.CreateChannel();
```

And this is how my current Behavior tag looks like in app.config :

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BasicBehavior">
      <CustomMessageInspector/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: You should not need to put it in a class library for it to function Some information on what problem/error you are encountering might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**:

```
ClientService clientService = new ClientService();

clientService.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new YourBehaviorThatApplysYourExtension());

InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(clientService);

DuplexChannelFactory<MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService> factory = new 
   DuplexChannelFactory<MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService>(context);
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = anvandarNamn;
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
return factory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: Pleas see my Edit1. How do I include your solution in this? Note that I need the msxItemInObjectGraph to be set.

Comment: You gave him the code to instantiate a service, he is trying to create a duplex client.